# Nokogiri::XML::Reader#encoding giving "nil"

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

Folks,

Have the following piece of code running on Nokogiri 1.5.6

```
require 'nokogiri'

reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(<<-eoxml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
<node label="Session">              
  <node id="session_query1" label="DTM Buffer Size" />
  <node id="session_query2" label="Buffer Block Size"/>
  <node id="session_query3" label="Enable Test Load"/>
</node>
<node label="Workflow" >
 <node id="workflow_query1" label="Enable HA Recovery"/>
 <node id="workflow_query2" label="Suspend on Error"/>
</node>
<node label="Mapping" >
 <node id="mapping_query1" label="SQL Override in SQ " />
 <node id="mapping_query2" label="SQL Override in lookup" />               
</node>
</root>
eoxml

p reader.instance_of? Nokogiri::XML::Reader #true
p reader.xml_encoding #nil
```

Does anyone know why xml_encoding is returning "nil"?

Comment: try this `reader.respond_to?(:xml_encoding,true) # => false`..But yes I don't know why `reader.encoding # => nil` Might be they have changed the API.

Comment: Myself raised one issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/980#issuecomment-26673638).. Let's wait.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it's `nil` because you passed it `nil`:

```
def Reader string_or_io, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = ParseOptions::STRICT
  # ...
end
```

I'd guess that's due to the `Reader` being an event-based parser, it won't always have that information available to it so it needs it passed in.

The `Document`-based parsing has it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

p Nokogiri::VERSION

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<-eoxml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
<node label="Session">              
  <node id="session_query1" label="DTM Buffer Size" />
  <node id="session_query2" label="Buffer Block Size"/>
  <node id="session_query3" label="Enable Test Load"/>
</node>
<node label="Workflow" >
 <node id="workflow_query1" label="Enable HA Recovery"/>
 <node id="workflow_query2" label="Suspend on Error"/>
</node>
<node label="Mapping" >
 <node id="mapping_query1" label="SQL Override in SQ " />
 <node id="mapping_query2" label="SQL Override in lookup" />               
</node>
</root>
eoxml

p doc.encoding
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe a change in the constructor to go through the first node and initialize the _encoding_ variable will fix this.